# Unable to upgrade from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-enterprise

**Preconditions**

Magento enterprise edition 2.3.4 ("magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.3.4") installed using composer method.

PHP version is 7.2.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Remove current vendor folder and composer.lock file
2. Run composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.5 --no-update
3. Run composer install

**Expected result**

composer install should complete successfully without errors

**Actual result**

Composer runs fine until this error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package is not installed: magento/project-enterprise-edition-2.3.5.0

Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php:114
 Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller->update() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:193
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->update() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:160
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:597
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:229
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:122
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:267
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:106
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:61
```